# Prolog loop after results

Tags: loops, prolog, declarative, failure-slice, declarative-programming

So I wrote this predicate to find all possible subsets + permutations of a list.
I get the correct output but for some reason the program keeps looping after giving me all the (correct) results.

What am I doing wrong?

```
% Gets all subsets of a list
aSubset([], []).
aSubset([E|Tail], [E|NTail]):- aSubset(Tail, NTail).
aSubset([_|Tail], NTail):- aSubset(Tail, NTail).

% gets all subsets and permutates them
allSubsets([],[]).
allSubsets(X, Res) :- permutation(S, Res), aSubset(X, S).
```

the results that I get for allSubsets([1,2,3], X) are:

```
4 ?- allSubsets([1,2,3], X).
X = [] ;
X = [1] ;
X = [2] ;
X = [3] ;
X = [1,2] ;
X = [1,3] ;
X = [2,3] ;
X = [2,1] ;
X = [3,1] ;
X = [3,2] ;
X = [1,2,3] ;
X = [1,3,2] ;
X = [2,1,3] ;
X = [2,3,1] ;
X = [3,1,2] ;
X = [3,2,1] ;
Action (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
```

where I have to abort the loop in the last two lines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only `allSubset([1,2,3], X)` loops, but also the much shorter `allSubset([], X)`.

The following program fragment ([failure-slice](/tags/failure-slice)) loops already. So no need to look any further.

```
allSubsets([],[]) :- false.
allSubsets(X, Res) :-
   permutation(S, Res), false,
   aSubset(X, S).
```

To improve this, you need to change something in the visible part. Currently, only Arg2 (`Res`) can influence the goal `permutation(S, Res)`, Arg1 (`X`) occurs only in the second goal, when it is already too late to influence (universal) termination of the first.

Comment: since I am new to prolog, I am not quite sure what would be a solution..
I also don't really understand what the 'wrong' part in my thinking is.

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt to state another way: your query to `permutation(S, Res)` is too "open-ended". Both arguments are variable. On backtracking, it will continue to generate and try permutations, *ad infinitum*, with ever increasing numbers of elements. You need to constrain it.

Comment: @lurker: What about posting a version that terminates "as good as a possible" Let's see how far we can go!

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt: Did you read other answers from the tag [tag:failure-slice]?

Answer (score 3):

One way to get there is a slight modification of your current code:

```
% Gets all subsets of a list
aSubset([], []).
aSubset([E|Tail], [E|NTail]):- aSubset(Tail, NTail).
aSubset([_|Tail], NTail):- aSubset(Tail, NTail).

% gets all subsets and permutates them
allSubsets([],[]).
allSubsets(X, Res) :- aSubset(X, S), permutation(S, Res).
```

So, rather than do an unbounded permutation first, generate a subset of the known list first (a finite number of solutions), then permute the known subset (also a finite number of solutions). Backtracking will do this across all permutations of all subsets:

```
| ?- allSubsets([1,2,3], L).

L = [1,2,3] ? a

L = [1,3,2]

L = [2,1,3]

L = [2,3,1]

L = [3,1,2]

L = [3,2,1]

L = [1,2]

L = [2,1]

L = [1,3]

L = [3,1]

L = [1]

L = [2,3]

L = [3,2]

L = [2]

L = [3]

L = []

(2 ms) no
| ?-
```

Comment: Which system gives you that result? I mean, are there really no semicolons (`;`) between the various `L`??

Comment: Argh, it could be Prolog GNU. Right?

Comment: @falseYes, if I press 'a' in GNU it doesn't show semicolons. It just lists all the results.